# include a file in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

am new in laravel, i have been searching for so on the net  but i couldn't  find a clear solution to this. i have a menu i want to include to  all admin pages

**menu.blade.php**

```
 @section('menu')
  <ul>
    <li><a href="{{URL::to('addHouse')}}">Add House</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{URL::to('addRenter')}}"></a>Add Renter</li>
    <li><a href="{{URL::to('addRoom')}}"></a>Add Rooms</li>
    <li><a href="{{URL::to('Payment')}}"></a>Payments</li>

 </ul>
@stop
```

**register.blade.php**

```
Register here
   @yield('menu')
```

But this is not working,  i don't know the way to go, please help

Comment: you might forget to use @extends('register') on `menu.blade.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include menu in admin pages you can do it this way:

**menu.blade.php**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="{{URL::to('addHouse')}}">Add House</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{URL::to('addRenter')}}"></a>Add Renter</li>
    <li><a href="{{URL::to('addRoom')}}"></a>Add Rooms</li>
    <li><a href="{{URL::to('Payment')}}"></a>Payments</li>
</ul>
```

**register.blade.php**

```
Register here
@include('menu')
```